# how to compare value with comma separated value in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to compare value with comma separated value in javascript or jquery. for that i did following code, what is remaining?:

```
 var str = $('#reg').val();
 // i got str = 1,2,3
```

i need to compare it with values so how can i do this:

```
if (str == 1) {
    $('.WBE').show();
} else {
    $('.WBE').hide();
}

if (str == 2) {
    $('.VOBE').show();
} else {
    $('.VOBE').hide();
}

if (str == 3) {
    $('.MBE').show();
} else {
    $('.MBE').hide();
}
```

Comment: Well, `"1,2,3" === "1"` is false, so you're going to have to be more specific ?

Comment: thats why i asked question. i dont know how to compare it comma saperately..

Comment: Are you saying if `str` contains 1 or if `str` contains 2 etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check if the string contains 1,2, or 3 then you can do like this:

```
var str = $('#reg').val();

if(str.indexOf("1") != -1) {
    $('.WBE').show();
} else {
    $('.WBE').hide();
}
if(str.indexOf("2") != -1) {
    $('.VOBE').show();
} else {
    $('.VOBE').hide();
}
if(str.indexOf("3") != -1) {
    $('.MBE').show();
} else {
    $('.MBE').hide();
}
```

**Or using ternary operator**

```
$('.WBE')[~str.indexOf('1') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
$('.VOBE')[~str.indexOf('2') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
$('.MBE')[~str.indexOf('3') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

**Looping through array and ternary operator**

```
['WBE', 'VOBE', 'MBE'].forEach(function(class, index) {
    $(class)[~str.index(index+1) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

This will only work if you have 0-9. If you have 2 or more digit numbers then you should probably convert to array and check if array contains the number...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string value to an array and check the values it contains using `$.inArray`:

```js
var values = $('#reg').val().split(',');
$('.WBE')[$.inArray('1', values) != -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
$('.VOBE')[$.inArray('2', values) != -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
$('.MBE')[$.inArray('3', values) != -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="WBE">WBE</div>
<div class="VOBE">VOBE</div>
<div class="MBE">MBE</div>

<input id="reg" value="1,3" />
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? You can see from the snippet that this should work fine given the information in your question.

Comment: yes in console i got following error:                                                                                                               $(...).val(...).split is not a function
 
}}],'errorCss':'error'});